# java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Double ERROR when using MAX()

Tags: google-cloud-dataprep

Since the update of Cloud Dataprep yesterday 19/11/2018, I got an error everytime I'm using the function MAX(), either alone or in pivot.

Some notes :

- I used the MAX function on another dataset and it was working. ( So max() works )
- I didn't have this issue before the update of dataprep yesterday, the
  flow was working.
- I tried many time to edit the recipe to isolate the
  issue but it seems to be that MAX() function
- The column i'm using MAX() on are of type INT. i tried to convert INT->
  FLOAT -> INT to make sure it's INT before using MAX() but keep getting the same issue

Here is the log

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Double
    at com.trifacta.google.dataflow.functions.MaxCombineFn.binaryOperation(MaxCombineFn.java:18)
    at com.trifacta.google.dataflow.functions.BinaryOperationCombineFn.addInput(BinaryOperationCombineFn.java:60)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.CombineFns$ComposedCombineFn.addInput(CombineFns.java:295)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.CombineFns$ComposedCombineFn.addInput(CombineFns.java:212)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.GlobalCombineFnRunners$CombineFnRunner.addInput(GlobalCombineFnRunners.java:109)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.PartialGroupByKeyParDoFns$ValueCombiner.add(PartialGroupByKeyParDoFns.java:163)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.PartialGroupByKeyParDoFns$ValueCombiner.add(PartialGroupByKeyParDoFns.java:141)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.GroupingTables$CombiningGroupingTable$1.add(GroupingTables.java:385)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.GroupingTables$GroupingTableBase.put(GroupingTables.java:230)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.GroupingTables$GroupingTableBase.put(GroupingTables.java:210)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.SimplePartialGroupByKeyParDoFn.processElement(SimplePartialGroupByKeyParDoFn.java:35)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:43)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:48)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.SimpleParDoFn$1.output(SimpleParDoFn.java:271)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.outputWindowedValue(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:309)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.access$700(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:77)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner$DoFnProcessContext.output(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:621)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.DoFnOutputReceivers$WindowedContextOutputReceiver.output(DoFnOutputReceivers.java:71)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.MapElements$1.processElement(MapElements.java:128)
```

Comment: I edited my answer so you know that the issue is now fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm with Google Cloud Platform Support.

This is is an internal issue that happened after the [update](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/release-notes) on the 19th (as you said). We know about this and we are working along the Trifacta team (as this is a third party product developed and managed by them).

There is a [Public Issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/119776862) regarding this, feel free to add info or anything you feel is needed.

EDIT: The issue is fixed now, could you try now and tell me if it worked?